# How do I get Numerators and Denominators of a fraction?

Tags: php

How do I get Numerators and Denominators of a fraction?
in php could I use explode(); ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$fraction='3/2';
$fractionParts=explode('/',$fraction);
$numerator=$fractionParts[0];
$denominator=$fractionParts[1];
```

Comment: Very nice, couldn't have dont it better +1

Comment: Thanks! You might want to re copy it, though (if you already copied it). I just corrected a few typos that I had at first.

Answer (score 2):

Why convert it to an array? The following is much simpler and will also be typecast to an integer:

```
$fraction='3/2';
sscanf($fraction, "%d/%d", $numerator, $denominator);
// $numerator and $denominator now have the values of 3 and 2, respectively
```